# Error 8 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly 'LibUsbDotNet' does not have a strong name

Tags: c#, dll, driver, lib

I am adding this "LibUsbDotNet".dll in my project but Error is coming

> Error 8 Assembly generation failed -- Referenced assembly
>   'LibUsbDotNet' does not have a strong name.

We are using 2 namespaces:

```
using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;
```

Our namespace is sBus and I am trying Signing there is checkbox Sign the assembly and I selected snk file there and 1 more "LibUsbDotNet" this has an only .dll file, not project

This now I am trying making driver for another project and that project same snk use this project but now this error is coming.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the LibUsbDotNet is not strongly named.

Strong naming of assmelby is done to avoid tampering of the assemblies.
You can read more about it [at this documentation link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/create-and-use-strong-named-assemblies)

Now, if that is not your project and somebody else's project, then you have three options:

- You can check if any strong named version of the same DLL or any other package which provides same functionality is available and refer that
- You can check the tools on git hub which help in strong naming the .DLL files
- Last option is to avoid strong name checking for this particular DLL.

Comment: I got that project and I add the strong name. Error solve